# Can't add constraints for Table View and Segmeted Conrol on View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints

I'm new in programming on swift and I try to do one app from some lessons and do step by step. But for some reason when I need to copy Table View on ViewController and set constraints - I can't do it, the same issue if I try add for example Segmented Control, I can't add constraints for him. If I create new VC and add there new Table View + Segmented Control, it's OK, I can add constraints for both. But not in my case, when I already done this Table View with all outlets and actions. 
Who knows how to fix it? Who had the same problem? Please, Help)))

This is the Storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correct , you cannot give contraint to a view that you copy from another viewcontroller if the view is main view in the source viewcontroller.

I found that problem on that case only, but I not do more research about why that happen

Example: copy tableview from tableviewcontroller to a viewcontroller

Edit:

You can copy tableviewcell without broke all the outlet and action connection

So just add tableview and copy the cell from other VC

Comment: so If I copy tableview from tableviewcontroller and this is one view there. But I can't add new view in tableVC to try change priority if it's possible. but how dude from these lessons created tableviewcontroller and copied table view on VC, I'm not sure, that he used tableVC to create his screen, but he couldn't add segmented control on it, and he copied tableview on new simple VC and he can do it now. So the only way is to create again tableview, but on VC from 0.)

Comment: maybe that problem happen in Xcode 11, not in older Xcode. I don't know which Xcode version that your lessons use. And usually, I did not use tableVC because it will take time to change it if I need to change/add view in the VC, better just use VC and add tableview

Comment: you can copy the Cell form other table and not broke the outlet @Kviki

Comment: thank you for your answer and explanation with advices, I'll follow them) I've done as you said and as I said in my comment  - it works fine.  Thank you!))

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You can solve it this way:

1. Create new ViewController
2. Put TableView in it
3. Put constraints on it
4. Copy Cell from previous TableView to new TableView in a new ViewController(constraints will not disappear from this cell)
5. Copy previous identifier of the TableView and delete old TableView
6. Connect new ViewController and sign it with old identifier.

Enjoy! :)